# SATA SSD GTP table will not reformat

Tags: gparted, gpt, fdisk, smart

I wanted to reformat my drive as msdos table so i could use it in another system without uefi and put a new installation on it since the laptop it was in died.

That said, i first tried gparted and got an input/output error, so i tried gnome-disk-utility and got the same type of error.

then i tried fdisk which also did not work and i learned that gdisk needs to be used on my gpt table.

gdisk reports its write as successful but after running partprobe i get:

```
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda1: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda2: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda3: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda4: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda5: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda6: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda7: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda1: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda2: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda3: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda4: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda5: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda6: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda7: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda1: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda2: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda3: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda4: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda5: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda6: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda7: Input/output error
Warning: Error fsyncing/closing /dev/sda: Input/output error
```

mind that none of these partitions should exist as i had already deleted all data, partition table and all using gdisk and had it report as successfully completed. After a reboot everything is the same as it was.

I cannot delete individual partitions either. S.M.A.R.T. reports that the drive is perfectly fine.

Comment: Try: sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd? - ?=a/b/c/d

Comment: Based on the error messages, it would appear that the drive is beginning to fail.  My experience with Seagate drives is that if the **Reallocated Sector Count** (check _smartctl_) starts to climb above zero, then it is time to look for a replacement drive.  It is also possible that the input/output hardware error is related to a loose cable, so that is another thing to check.

Comment: dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sd (a in my case) has been tried. the drive is Crucial MX100 256GB SATA 2.5-Inch Internal Solid State Drive. I also tried other cables and a different tower. If the drive is indeed bad then i should be covered under warranty which is great, but i'll have to wait awhile for the replacement..

Comment: Have you got solution for this? I have the same drive (500Gb version) and same problem in gparted. The drive lost the ntfs partitions (appears as raw/unformatted) but the SMART report is clean.

Comment: I got a replacement from crucial, was no big deal. I posted an answer to reflect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up sending the drive to crucial for a replacement. It seems that the majority (or all) of the blocks had been write protected. My research shows that this is somewhat common in the line of crucial drives (no source, sorry, i found this some months ago now and not about to go looking for it atm).

Good news for me is i was able to save my data and got a replacement drive, only worry is it having the same issue after a year or two of use.